# Problem with finding Maximum value

Tags: derivatives

My problem states: Show that y:
\begin{equation}
y = e^{-t}sin(2t)
\end{equation}
is a maximum when
\begin{equation}
t =
\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(2)
\end{equation}
and determine this maximum value.

So basically i have to calculate first and second derivatives of function f(t) = y and find some relation with what i must prove. Well, i've almost done it i think. But not quite. Can someone help me by checking out my answer a bit and tell me where i'm wrong, what i should improve, anything that could help me really?

So first i calculate first derivative:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dt} = -e^{-t}\sin(2t) + 2e^{-t}\cos(2t)
\end{equation}
and i convert the result to a more simplified form
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{5}e^{-t}\cos(2t-0.464)
\end{equation}
which i equate to 0 to find t(which i can't find it here).
And then i calculate the second derivative:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}} = -\sqrt{5}e^{-t}\cos(2t-0.464)-2\sqrt{5}e^{-t}\sin(2t-0.464)
\end{equation}
which "simplifies" to:
\begin{equation}
5e^{-t}\cos(2(t-\frac{tan^{-1}(2)}{2})-0.4636)
\end{equation}
I doubt i'm right so far but if i am then i'm close. However i don't see exactly how i can prove what is needed from here. If someone could help me a bit i would be most grateful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have been better off trying to solve for critical points directly in:
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -e^{-t}\sin(2t) + 2e^{-t}\cos(2t)$$
instead of first simplifying.
$$0 = -e^{-t}\sin(2t) + 2e^{-t}\cos(2t) \implies e^{-t}\sin(2t) = 2e^{-t}\cos(2t)$$
and that gives
$$\tan(2t) = 2$$

Comment: Ah i see. One question. Are we always allowed to divide by an expression that has the variable in it? For example you have divided by e^-t . I didn't know that was (always) possible.

Comment: Yes with a caveat, $e^{-t}$ for each t is just a number, so as long as it isn't zero, you can divide both sides by it.  If it is zero, you need to consider that case separately.  However, $e^{-t}$ is always positive.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me understand.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra  Great!